# how to find if specifc version is outdated

Tags: python, pip

Is there a way to know if specific version is outdated? I know I can use pip list -o, but this goes over all packages, and I would like to get only for specific version.

thanks.
Eran

Comment: You mean list all packages that their version for example are greater that 3?

Comment: @Farhadix, I mean to check if specific package installed on my computer can be updated (e.g. has newer version on the respository). thx.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly workaround:
create virtualenv, install demanded package with pip, use pip list -o in both real environment and virtual one, compare output...